# How can i put condition in ul for count message for specific person message?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

This is my code of fetching data from database.

**Model**:-

```
public function fetch_data($v)
{  


            if($v != '')
            {
                $this->db->set('chat_status', '0');
                $this->db->where('chat_status','1');
                $this->db->update('chat');
            }
                $this->db->select("receiver_id");
                $this->db->from("chat");
                $this->db->where("chat_status", "1");
                $this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
                $this->db->limit(1);
                $result = $this->db->get();
                $output = '';


    $this->db->select("receiver_id");
    $this->db->from("chat");
    $this->db->where("chat_status", "1");
    $this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $result1 = $this->db->get();
    $count=$result1->num_rows();

    $data= array('unseen_notification'=>$count);
    return json_encode($data);

}
```

this is my controller

**Controller**:-

```
public function index()
{ 
$v=$this->input->post('view');
echo $op= $this->Notify_Model->fetch_data($v);
return $op;
}
```

and this is my ajax and view for calling notification in view

**Ajax**:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function load_unseen_notification(view = '')
{

$.ajax({
url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Notify/index",
method:"POST",
data:{"view":view},
dataType:"json",
success:function(data)
{
 $('.dropdown-menu').html(data.notification);
 $('.count').show();
 if(data.unseen_notification > 0)
 {    
  $('.count').html(data.unseen_notification);
 }  else if(data.unseen_notification == ''){
     $('.count').hide();
 }
}
});
}
load_unseen_notification();
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(){
$('.count').html('');
load_unseen_notification('yes');
});
setInterval(function(){
load_unseen_notification();
}, 1000);
});
```

and this is my **View** where i called notification count:

```
<ul class="users-list clearfix">
                <?php
                    $this->db->select();
                    $this->db->from("chat");
                    $this->db->where("sender_id", $this->session->userdata('id'));
                    $this->db->where("chat_status", "1");
                    $this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
                    $result = $this->db->get();
                if($result)
                {
                ?>
                <li style="width: 0px;padding: 0px;">
                  <span class="label label-pill count" style="border-radius:10px;color: black;"></span>
                </li>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                <?php if(!empty($adminslist)){
                    foreach($adminslist as $v):
        ?>
                    <li class="selectVendor" id="<?=$v['id'];?>" title="<?=$v['fname'];?>">
                      <img src="<?=base_url('/assets/uploads/' . $v['img']);?>" alt="<?=$v['fname'];?>" title="<?=$v['fname'];?>">
                      <a class="users-list-name" href="#"><?=$v['fname'];?></a>
                      <!--<span class="users-list-date">Yesterday</span>-->
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach;?>

               <?php }else{?>
                <li>
                   <a class="users-list-name" href="#">No Admin Find...</a>
                 </li>
                <?php } ?>


              </ul>
```

how can i set condition for count message for specific person in this.. I try this code but doesn't work and i set condition in view model.

Comment: Shouldn't you be querying the notifications by receiver id instead of sender, I mean instead of `$this->db->where("sender_id", $this->session->userdata('id'));` shouldn't it be something like `$this->db->where("receiver_id", $this->session->userdata('id'));` ?

Comment: i tried but count will increase with all users not specific user

Comment: Having your view perform a database operation is kinda fundamentally wrong to begin with …

Comment: ok so let me check